# What happens when C17H35COO-, a soap, reacts with an acidic solution?

Tags: acid-base, fats

My book says that-

> In acidic water, the negative fatty acid ions become fatty acids.

However, they did not include a chemical equation to demonstrate this, so I made my own:

$$\ce{C17H35COO- (aq) + HCl (aq) -> C17H35COOH (aq) + Cl- (aq)}$$

But according to this equation, the fatty acid ion is a base, since it gets a proton. So this must be wrong. Can anyone point out my mistakes (if any), and explain what happens when a negative fatty acid ion comes in contact with acidic water, and becomes a fatty acid?

Comment: Here's a thought: Try adding vinegar to a solution of soap and water. Will this be enough to break down all soap, and cancel out the effect of the soap molecules totally? Why / Why not?

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is correct. Hydrochloric acid ($\ce{HCl}$) is a stronger acid than stearic acid ($\ce{C17H35COOH}$),i.e. it is dissociated into $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{X-}$, the anionic rest, to a greater degree. Therefore, it protonates the stearate ion. One can also say that the conjugated base of stearic acid (the stearate ion) is a stronger base than chloride, the conjugated base of hydrochloric acid.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, soap in acidic water just means reactions with the hydrogen ions in acid and whatever other element in the acids is not a matter to be concerned about. For example, sodium stearate $\ce{C17H35COONa}$ decomposes in in acidic water soap:

\begin{align}
\ce{C17H35COONa &-> \underset{\text{(stearate ion)}}{C17H35COO-} + \underset{\text{(sodium ion)}}{Na+}} \\
\ce{C17H35COO- +  \underset{\text{(from any acid)}}{H+} &-> \underset{\text{(stearic acid)}}{C17H35COOH}}
\end{align}

Due to the formation of stearic acid, soap cannot act efficiently in acidic water.